# using the stacking module in rapidminer

Tags: machine-learning, classification, rapidminer

iam new to rapidminer and i know how to add neuralnets and aply model and how to use the crossvalidation. but now i want to use the stacking module but i get the error that my neural net can't work with binominal fields but it did before i started using the stack module.

in my stack module in the left part i have 2 adaboosts with in the first a neural net and in de second a naive byas. in the right part i have a singel neural net wich gives the error how can i fix this? i have looked at the questions but i couldn't find any thing about using multiple learners. and google isn't as usefull as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The neural network operator fails because the base learner output adds new polynominal attributes to the training data which are then used by the stacking model learner. Neural networks can handle numeric attributes only.

You would need to transform the polynominals to numbers in some way.